# Code Snippet is not inserting code

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

i use to be using Code Snippet, but now for some time i can't use it, because when click on <kbd>Insert into Post</kbd> nothing happens and in console there is no errors. Using Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Confirmed, it's not working D:

Comment: I broke this last week and fixed it this morning. Sorry for the inconvenience.